# 12V voltage regulator with the least drop out voltage

Tags: voltage, lm317, voltage-regulator

I have a DC adapter rating 12 V 750 mA. I broke open its case and saw that its rectified but not regulated.

I need 12 V for my design and do not want to buy a transformer. Do you know of any regulator with the least dropout voltage?

I know LM317 is adjustable and its Vdo is 1.2 V(min) but can't use that because then regulated voltage will be 10.8 V and I need 12V regulated.

I haven't tested the adapter yet, will do that tomorrow its offload voltage.

Answer (score 5):

What you need is an **LDO** (Low DropOut) regulator. The Micrel [MIC2937](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mic2937.pdf) has a dropout of only 370 mV at 750 mA out.

You'll have to check the output voltage of the adapter at maximum current. Connect a 16 \$\Omega\$/10 W resistor and measure the voltage. You can combine resistors you have in your box, keeping in mind that P = V\$^2\$/R. The voltage should be higher than 12.4 V.

The MIC29372 (same datasheet) is a version with adjustable output, which may be of help if the output voltage isn't high enough for 12 V out.

**edit**
If the voltage is too low, and you really want to use the adapter, you can replace the rectifier diodes with Schottky types. That will give you an extra volt output.

**edit 2** (regarding the LM317 *hli* also proposes)
If it's a 12 V adapter it will deliver about 12 V under load. Saying that the unloaded voltage is high enough for the LM317 is meaningless; you do want to *use* it, don't you? 12 V, even a bit higher is insufficient for the LM317. Don't design for unreliability and use an LDO.

**edit 3** (2012-06-14, re your comment)
If the adapter is only going to be used only for powering a relay you don't need a regulator. The relay will only show a small load to the 12 V, so it may well be a few volts higher (unloaded transformers output a higher than nominal voltage). [This relay](http://components.omron.com/components/web/PDFLIB.nsf/0/0293ACA6B03161CD86257538007424DB/%24file/G5LE_0911.pdf) is rated at 12 V, but has a maximum voltage 1.7 \$\times\$ that, so that's 20.4 V, which should be safe. Nominal power is 360 mW, and that will be somewhat higher at 15 V for instance (560 mW). If the voltage at 30 mA load is much higher than the 12 V you could still use a regulator. This will also consume some power, but the sum of regulator and relay power would be less than the relay alone.

Also nice about it is *Must operate voltage*, which is maximum 75 % of rated voltage. That means it will still work if the adapter's voltage would drop a few volts. The Micrel regulator will drop less than 200 mV at 30 mA, if we go for the adjustable, and choose 10 V out, then we will have proper regulation down to 10.2 V in, and the relay will only consume 250 mW instead of 360 mW. So we win twice.

Comment: thanks man i searched on farnell and thats wat i found. Ure the man u answer most of my questions

Comment: @David - Always glad to help. How's the optocoupler thing going?

Comment: Actually thats wat im doing rite now. Shud i post my answer as a new question? Or in the same thread where u explained everything

Comment: @David - Keep things separate. This is power supply, the optocoupler is a different problem, even if it's for the same product. If you want feedback on what you're doing, post it as an update to the original question, and make clear that you want feedback. Success!

Comment: @David - Another thing. If you post a schematic, even if hand drawn, make sure the components have a *refdes* (reference designator), which identifies them, like "R1" or "IC1". It's much easier to discuss it that way.

Comment: awesome will do, most probably tomorrow. Ure the man steven. Im getting bak to work now

Comment: wouldn't 12V unregulated mean that 12V*sqrt(2)=16.9V and it's plenty for any linear regulator like 7812 or LM317, given that you have enough capacitance before regulator to make sure the ripple never falls below 14V?

Comment: @miceuz - If it has a DC output it will refer to that, not the transformer's secondary's voltage, which means nothing to an average user. But being unregulated the voltage may be way higher than 12 V unloaded.

Comment: Note that the 1.2V reference voltage of the LM317 is irrelevant to how much dropout you get at 12V. The 1.2V is scaled up by 10x to provide 12V output and an LDO with a 1.2V reference COULD have eg 0.1V dropout. The LM317's dropout is specified separately and is not marvellous. It's around 2 Volt when Iout is 750 mA.

Comment: @Russell - Interpreting the datasheet strictly it's even 3 V. That's the test condition for the reference voltage.

Comment: @stevenvh - Lm317 dropout is manufacturer, model, temperature and current dependant. Datasheets tend not to have tabled value - only graphs, which should be read as typical. [Datasheet here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00000455.pdf) 3V a bit high - especially at with TO220 and at 750 mA. 2V (which was from memory) happens to be about right. High, regardless.

Comment: @miceuz - Even if it were 12V AC the 16.97 V peak might still not be sufficient, and surely not "plenty". You've got two 1 V drops across the rectifier bridge, that leaves 14.97 V. [Some LM317s](https://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM117.pdf) only specify Vref for a minimum Vin - Vout of 3 V. That leaves 0 V for ripple, and that's impossible. For this regulator you'll need a 15 V transformer.

Comment: I tested the adapter and getting 11.8V output instead of 12V. I needed to drive my relay with 12V.

Comment: @David - 12 V relays also work at 11.8 V. In the datasheet it's called "must operate voltage". I've seen 12 V relays where that was 8.4 V. Also added about Schottky diodes in my answer. BTW, is that 12 V only for the relay? Then it doesn't have to be regulated.

Comment: are u sure? I thot it has to be regulated and no i will not be using 12V for anything else. I need to discuss a relay circuit but i will post that as a new question.

Comment: *What do you mean: are you sure?* Would I ever lie to you? :-) Read [this datasheet](http://components.omron.com/components/web/PDFLIB.nsf/0/0293ACA6B03161CD86257538007424DB/$file/G5LE_0911.pdf), for instance. It says "Max. voltage: 130% of rated voltage at 85°C, 170% of rated voltage at 23°C". That's 20 V at room temperature. It will consume more power, but that would go to the regulator otherwise. Note that it also says "Must operate voltage: 75% max. of rated voltage (max.)" That means it will work from 9 V to 20 V.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could go with the LM317. Usually, the voltage output of such power supplies is higher that stated when they are not under full load.

Remember, the transformer delivers an AC voltage (a sine wave). When it is rectified, you get sine half-waves. Their peak voltage is (assuming the transformer delivers 12V AC) 12V*sqrt(2)=16.9 volts. When you then add a capacitor, you get 16.9V DC voltage (when there is no load connected, nothing discharges the capacitor). Depending on the load, the voltage drops. (I remember a basic guideline of using 3000µF capacitor per ampere of output, but I don't know how good this advice is).

So you should just try using a LM317, and measure the voltages under the load you expect for your project.

Btw: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier) explains the rectification much better than I can...

Comment: An answer to a comment to my answer: Even if it were 12V AC the 16.97 V peak might still not be sufficient, and surely not "plenty". You've got two 1 V drops across the rectifier bridge, that leaves 14.97 V. [Some LM317s](https://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM117.pdf) only specify Vref for a minimum Vin - Vout of 3 V. That leaves 0 V for ripple, and that's impossible. For this regulator you'll need a 15 V transformer.

Comment: You can evaluate how good the advice of 3mF per Ampère is: at 50 Hz with half wave (10 ms low), 1 mA will be equal to 10 µC: with 3 mF capacitor, it'll be a drop of 10µ/3m = 3.3 mV. Errors excluded :)

Comment: @stevenvh: whoops, I've considered 1 mA instead of 1 A! Well, in that case it would be perfect! Even overkill

Comment: Ignore clabacchio's comment, he's confused, too much drinking ;-). V = I \$\cdot\$ t / C = 1 A \$\cdot\$ 10 ms / 3 mF = 3.3 V. That leaves 11.7V!!!  From my first comment you know that you don't have a mV to spare.

Comment: By the way, rectification is free these days? It's not because Wikipedia doesn't mention diode voltage drops that they don't exist. They do! 1 V per diode. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: -1. Why do you assume 12V AC? Like stevenvh says: "If it has a DC output the mentioned voltage will refer to that, not the transformer's secondary's voltage, which means nothing to an average user." For 12V DC under load you use a 10V transformer.

Comment: But we don't know anything about the project of @clabacchio - especially not the current needs. In my experience a unregulated power supply rated for 12V under full load easily reaches 17V without any load, most times even more. And since this 12V output already includes the voltage drop of the 2 diodes (depending on the transformer, it might even only one), it should be rated as 12V AC. That's why I recommended measuring what happens under the load which is to be expected.

Comment: @stevenvh: Look at the datasheet you have linked, page 6. For a current of 1A (which is way above what the power supply in question can deliver) the dropout voltage gets only above 2V when the temperature sinks below room temperature. With 500mA load, you can expect 1.7V dropout voltage.

Comment: If the reference voltage is specified at 3V drop it means it can/will be different at lower drops. You can't rely on it no more.